# MEF ImportMany not working with Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

Here is my metadata:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ModuleAttribute : ExportAttribute, IModuleMetadata
{
    public ModuleAttribute(string Contract) : base(Contract,typeof(IScreen))
    {            
        Region = Region.Sidebar;
        IsVisible = true;
        Order = short.MaxValue;
        Description = string.Empty;
    }

    public string Module { get; set; }        
    public Region Region { get; set; }        
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }        
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public short Order { get; set; }
}
```

My interface:

```
public interface IModuleMetadata
{       
   string Module { get; set; }
   Region Region { get; set; }
   string DisplayName { get; set; }
   bool IsVisible { get; set; }
   string Description { get; set; }
   short Order { get; set; }
}
```

I am accessing using:

```
[ImportMany]
public IEnumerable<Lazy<IScreen, IModuleMetadata>> Mods
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

But always my Mods end up being `null`.

Update:

```
[Module("Unit", Module = "Stock")]
class UnitViewModel : BaseViewModel, ICUDB, IHandle<UnitModel>
{
```

Interestingly, when I ask using GetExport. I am getting all the 15 exported classes.

```
var ex = container.GetExports<IScreen, JIMS.Common.Interface.IModuleMetadata>();
```

Comment: Show us how you use ModuleAttribute. The problem probably lies there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check to make sure you are matching contracts which means digging into the metadata. While I recommend doing that so you can see how MEF puts all the pieces-parts together, you should try specifying the [type for `ImportMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833131%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is how BaseViewModel is created. If you did a new BaseViewModel() from the shell or other location, MEF won't work its magic inside the class. MEF needs to create any object that will be using MEF.

Comment: My BaseViewModel is inherited from Screen which implements IScreen

Comment: This doesn't matter, it all depends on how the object is created.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a contract for the export you will need the same contract for the import.

Like:

```
[ImportMany("Unit")]
public IEnumerable<Lazy<IScreen, IModuleMetadata>> Mods
```

**Another** way to make this work is to modify the export to:

```
[Module(null, Module = "Stock")]
class UnitViewModel : BaseViewModel, ICUDB, IHandle<UnitModel>
```

By passing null or the empty string as a contract then the type will be used.

If you don't always need a contract then you can add a parameterless .ctor to `ModuleAttribute`.

Comment: No help from this, I tried what you said, but still it's null

Comment: Have you tried without a contract? Remove it from both export (by setting it to null) and import (leave it as it is). If it still doesn't work create your composition container with the DisableSilentRejection option on and check the rejection cause.